# How to save file getting from HTTP GET response on disk file java

Tags: java, file, pdf, httpresponse, http-get

I am getting a file in response to the HTTP GET request. I tried the following curl command which is providing me the exact output that I want:

`curl -X GET <URL> -H 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' --output <Path on local machine>/Test.pdf`

Can someone provide a java code to save this file on my local storage without using an external library?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to write the code and get some practice on java.net and java.io packages?

Please take a look at class [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and method [openStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream()) for getting access to content.

You can then save that by leveraging Java File IO, classes of interest would be [BufferedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) for reading content and [BufferedOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) for saving content.

Please refer [File IO Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)